# Knockout.js: How to dynamically bind a field to an attribute of an object, which in turn is in an Array of siblings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am building an HTML page which sends and gets data from a REST Api (as part of an SPA).

For a specific entity, it shall be possible to create its content in several languages (number of languages is variable by user).

Let's imagine an entity with one field: "Field1". I want to be able, in the GUI, to enter the value of Field1 for different languages and then send back to the REST Api a JSON array of those entities.

The idea is to have a language selector and one form that is reused for each language. Field1 of this form shall be binded to an observable object which contains the language and Field1 value. An array would hold those objects.

The following Fiddle shows what I have done and it works as expected (the array is updated accordingly). **But being a beginner in Knockout I have the feeling that my solution is really not the best one....**

http://jsfiddle.net/rtacsltng/sb4ws0dj/   (fiddle code is also added below)

In particular, in order to update the Array (elementArray), I've subscribed to Field1 but I have the feeling that there might be a more elegant/efficient way to do that.

---

Also, another question: I haven't declared elementArray as observable, since I am only interested in "observing" its elements. Is it right?

---

Finally, to increase the complexity, note that in the final version, the field will be declared through a custom binding (see [Material Design Lite: How to programatically reset a floating label input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957407) where Roy J nicely explained me how to do so). Do you think its possible to integrate this custom binding in the overall "mechanism"?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**HTML**

```
Please choose a language first (en = English, sp = Spanish)
<br>
<br>
<form>
    <select data-bind="
                        options: availableLangs,
                        optionsCaption: 'Choose Language',
                        value: chosenLang;
                    "></select>
    <input type="text" id="field1" data-bind="value: field1, valueUpdate: 'keypress'" />
</form>
<br>Value of Field in English: <span data-bind="text: elementArray[0].elementField1"></span>

<br>Value of Field in Spanish: <span data-bind="text: elementArray[1].elementField1"></span>
```

---

**JS**

```
function EditableElement(lang) {
    var self = this;
    self.elementLang = lang;
    self.elementField1 = ko.observable();
}

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableLangs = [ //Available languages
    "en",
        "sp"];

    self.field1 = ko.observable("");

    self.field1.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.elementArray[self.chosenLangIndex()].elementField1(newValue);
    });


    self.elementArray = [];
    for (var i = 0, arrLength = self.availableLangs.length; i < arrLength; i++) {
        self.elementArray.push(new EditableElement(self.availableLangs[i]));
    }

    self.chosenLang = ko.observable("");
    self.chosenLangIndex = ko.observable("");
    self.chosenLang.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.chosenLangIndex(self.availableLangs.indexOf(newValue));
        self.field1("");
    });
}

var vm = new MyViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: As a guiding principle, it's better to have `computed`s rather than copies of data in multiple `observable`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Entirely updated**

Now that I understand what you're trying to do, let's do this completely differently! The input field is now the *dependent* field: depending on which language is chosen, it reads/writes one of the values you want to save.

I fleshed out the availableLanguages structure and then made a dictionary of `savedValues` indexed by the language code. The input field is a writable computed that picks one of the `savedValues` entries based on the chosen language. No clearing the field when you change languages, it is automatically set to whatever is saved in the appropriate place.

I also hid the field when no language is selected, because it doesn't map to anything then.

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  //Available languages
  self.availableLangs = [{
    code: "en",
    name: 'English'
  }, {
    code: "sp",
    name: 'Spanish'
  }];

  self.chosenLang = ko.observable("");

  self.savedValues = {};

  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.availableLangs, function(langInfo) {
    self.savedValues[langInfo.code] = ko.observable();
  });

  self.saveValue = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      var lang = self.chosenLang();
      return lang ? self.savedValues[lang]() : '';
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
      var lang = self.chosenLang();
      if (lang) {
        self.savedValues[lang](newValue);
      }
    }
  });
}

var vm = new MyViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Please choose a language first (en = English, sp = Spanish)
<br>
<br>
<form>
  <select data-bind="options: availableLangs,
                     optionsCaption: 'Choose Language',
                     optionsText: 'name',
                     optionsValue: 'code',
                     value: chosenLang;
                    "></select>
  <input type="text" id="field1" data-bind="value: saveValue, valueUpdate: 'input', visible: chosenLang" />
</form>
<div data-bind="foreach: availableLangs">
  <br>Value of Field in <span data-bind="text:name"></span>: <span data-bind="text: $parent.savedValues[code]()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy! The thing is that I need to keep an array of the different input for the different langs: at the end, I want to send back to the backend Rest API a JSON which is an array of objects i.e. [
                {lang: "en", field1: "en_value"},
                {lang: "sp", field1: "sp_value"}
            ]  
This is why I had an Array of observables (elementArray) which holds the different objects populated through the same unique form epending on the language selected. My question is how to elegantly bind field1 to the corresponding array element depending on the language chosen.

Comment: And actually a bi-directional binding between field1 and the corresp. array element would be top. We could choose a lang, enter a value in the field, switch to the 2nd lang, enter the value for this lang, switch back to the 1st lang and the field displays the value originally entered for the 1st lang. This way we use one form for keying-in values for several langs and maintaining an array of these values ready to be sent to the API. In the final app, there will be more than one field but also more than 2 languages (user will choose the langs he wants -availableLangs will be observable-). TIA!

Comment: @3371862 So there ya go.

Comment: Brilliant :-) 1000 thanks for your help and how it helps progressing with knockout!